# About iTunes Connect

Tags: app-store-connect

I am having problems with banking informations on iTunes Connect. I am brazilian and everything was working fine, but now they're asking for IBAN (International Bank Account Number) and I can't find how to get that number anywhere! Anyone know how to get it? Is it necessary? I Heard that it is just necessary for european countries..

Answer (score 0):

IBAN for Brazilian bank accounts is [effective](http://www.swift.com/dsp/resources/documents/IBAN_Registry.pdf) as of 1st of July 2013. You can contact your bank to learn your IBAN.

Answer (score 0):

Your **IBAN** should be located on your bank account statement. If you can not find the **IBAN** on your ban account statement, then you should be able to contact your bank's firm and they should be able to help you get that.

This is the *Irish Payment Services Organisation Limited*'s website. I know you are not Irish, but it is the **IBAN**, so it all works with the same rules and terms.

Link: http://www.ipso.ie/section/biciban